# Python Pandas replacing a specific value anywhere in a dataframe with the corresponding row value in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace all "True" values in a dataframe with the value of the corresponding row in the first column

For example:

I have this dataframe:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | True | 0 | True |
| DEF | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GHI | 0 | True | 0 |
| JKL | True | 0 | 0 |
| MNO | 0 | True | True |

Whenever the value in the whole dataframe is "True" I want to replace it with the corresponding value in column 1

The output should be like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | 0 | ABC |
| DEF | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GHI | 0 | GHI | 0 |
| JKL | JKL | 0 | 0 |
| MNO | 0 | MNO | MNO |

I tried replace function but I am not able to identify the value to be replaced with the first column value
I tried where and loc but they require to specify the column location where True value is present

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiplication and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
# select the columns to use
cols = df.columns.difference(['column1'])

# identify values to change, assuming "True" is a string here
mask = df[cols].eq('True')

# update in place
df.update(mask.mul(df['column1'], axis=0).where(mask, df[cols]))
```

Output:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4
0     ABC     ABC       0     ABC
1     DEF       0       0       0
2     GHI       0     GHI       0
3     JKL     JKL       0       0
4     MNO       0     MNO     MNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `axis=0` by mask comparing `True` like string, if `True` is boolean use `df.eq(True)`:

```
out = df.mask(df.eq('True'), df['column1'], axis=0)
print (out)
  column1 column2 column3 column4
0     ABC     ABC       0     ABC
1     DEF       0       0       0
2     GHI       0     GHI       0
3     JKL     JKL       0       0
4     MNO       0     MNO     MNO
```

You can specify columns - here all without first use subset:

```
c = df.columns[1:].tolist()

df[c] = df[c].mask(df[c].eq('True'), df['column1'], axis=0)
print (df)
  column1 column2 column3 column4
0     ABC     ABC       0     ABC
1     DEF       0       0       0
2     GHI       0     GHI       1
3     JKL     JKL       0       0
4     MNO       0     MNO     MNO
```